# Can not run the command: git add . && git commit -m "Initial commit'

Tags: git

I can not run the command: git add . && git commit -m "Initial commit'
I give an error:
Pathspec commit did not match any fields known to git

Comment: You have a double quote opening the message and a single quote closing it. Is it a typo in your question? If not, you have an answer!

Comment: If previous comment is not the answer, does the command `git add . ` works ?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The quote issue on commit does not always matter here: in a CMD, that would work.

The '&&' can be problematic depending on your bash session.

Try instead

```
 git add .; git commit -m "Initial commit"
```